# Wrap stray text in divs

Tags: jquery

How do I select "anything that doesn't have a containing tag" to add a wrapper in jQuery? ex:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="whatever">This should remain untouched</div>
    I want to wrap this in div.red
</div>
```

The result would be this

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="whatever">This should remain untouched</div>
    <div class="red">I want to wrap this in div.red</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to select the text nodes. Try this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RTBFn/5/)) :

```
$('.post').each(function() {
    var data = [];
    $(this).contents().each(function() {
        if ( this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ) {
            data.push(this);
        }
    }).end().append( $('<div class="red" />').append(data) );
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="whatever">This should remain untouched</div>
    I want to wrap this in div.red
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.red{background:red}
```

Comment: I would favor `.contents().filter().wrap()`, as at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10005977/2336725