# How to wrap HTML around a text node with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="pagination">
  <a href="#">1</a>
  <a href="#">2</a>
  3
  <a href="#">4</a>
</div>
```

I need to use jQuery to wrap an HTML element around the number "3". I can't modify the HTML because it is dynamically generated.

Comment: I think that will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568657/wrap-stray-text-in-divs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this will wrap all your number with a span, so the structure will be :

```
<a><span>1</span></a>
```

and the selected one only span without a :

```
<span>2</span>


var html = $('.pagination').html();
    html = html.replace(/[0-9]/g,"<span>$&</span>");
    $('.pagination').html(html);
```

so you can easily style it with :

```
.pagination a span {normal style} 
.pagination span{selected style}
```

Comment: @user560756 or you won't be notified.

Comment: why not simply  `$('.pagination').html('<span>'+$('.pagination').html()+'</span>');`

Answer (score 15):

I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9886020/575527) which wraps all stray text

```
$(function() {

    var test = $('.pagination')
        .contents()
        .filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== '';
        })
        .wrap('<span/>');

});​
```

just had a minor confusion with `wrap()` and `wrapAll()`. [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8y4GX/)

Comment: it changed the order of the elements http://jsbin.com/uvigam/edit#javascript,html

Comment: it's now updated. this time, i have a demo. i got confused with `wrap()` and `wrapAll()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but a shorter, simpler way to do this in my opinion would be:

```
$("div:not(a)").wrapInner("<a href='#'></a>");
```