# Is it possible to find a text in a parent element and wrap it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a snippet of code that looks like that:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <a href="#">Root element</a>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    Page 2
</div>
```

What I am looking to do, and I am not sure if that it is possible is to convert the above snippet to the following by using jQuery:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <a href="#">Root element</a>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    <span class="paginationSection">Page 2</span>
</div>
```

Is there a way to achive that with jQuery ?

**UPDATE #1**

This is the code as I have made it in order to work for me. I am placing the code here just for help other peopleon in the feature.

```
// Get the breadcrumb element
var t = document.getElementsByClassName('breadcrumbs');
// Assign the breadcrumb element into t variable
var t = t[0];
// Get the text of the last node in the breadcrumb element
var currentText = t.childNodes[t.childNodes.length - 1].nodeValue;

// If currentText it is not empty
if($.trim(currentText) != '')
{
    // Create a new span element
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    // Set the class I need
    span.className = 'pagination';
    // Set the text to currentText
    span.innerHTML = currentText;
    // Empty the last node value
    t.childNodes[t.childNodes.length - 1].nodeValue = '';
    // Append the span on .breadcrumb element.
    t.appendChild(span);
}
```

*Finally I like to thank all of you for your participation in this question :)*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wrap HTML around a text node with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005834/how-to-wrap-html-around-a-text-node-with-jquery)

Comment: The dublication you provide doesn't help me at all. It is not meet my need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.breadcrumbs').text().wrap('<span class="paginationSection" />');
```

**Update:**

Try this one:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jNDC3/)

```
$('.breadcrumbs').text(function(index,text){return this.text}).wrap('<span class="paginationSection" />');
```

**Update2:**

This is best way to do by which actual problem would be solved as your question requirement: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jNDC3/1/)

```
$('.breadcrumbs').contents()
.filter(function(){
return this.nodeType !== 1;
}).wrap('<span class="paginationSection" />');
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me :(. Not I have clear my cache and I am sure for the class selector used.

Comment: just to let you know, It will create an empty HTML element with class `paginationSection` for each node.  You can check this by inspecting the output

Comment: Oh! I just see that thanks. using trim would remove that. http://jsfiddle.net/jNDC3/2/

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, the following assumes that the text 'Page 2' will be the only text node inside `.breadcrumbs`. Check that the node value isn't just whitespace with `$.trim()`:

```
$('.breadcrumbs').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue);
}).wrap('<span class="paginationSection"></span>');
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/xcBNU/5/)

Comment: This is also converting the whitespace between the anchors into spans. See http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/xcBNU/3/

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do this using

```
document.getElementsByClassName('breadcrumbs')[0].innerHTML = 
          document.getElementsByClassName('breadcrumbs')[0]
          .innerHTML
          .replace('Page 2', '<span class="paginationSection">Page 2</span>')
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JZ37H/)

---

Based on your [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134905/is-it-possible-to-find-a-text-in-a-parent-element-and-wrap-it#comment31805693_21135074),  I have updated like

```
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('breadcrumbs')[0];
var rege = /Page \d+/;
var matchy = ele.innerHTML.match(rege);
ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML.replace(matchy, '<span class="paginationSection">'+ matchy +'</span>')
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZ37H/3/)

Comment: Hard-coding the text doesn't seem right. He almost certainly needs a more general solution.

Comment: This it seem will not work, due to "Page X" is dynamic.

Comment: yes you're right.  I think a regex can be used here to overcome it

Comment: @Barmar I have updated my answer using regex, so now it will be dynamic.  Hope this is right?

Comment: @MerianosNikos I have updated my answer, give a try.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan Thanks a lot for your contribution. The broblem is solved. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible

```
var t = $(".breadcrumbs")[0];
t.innerHTML = t.innerHTML.replace('Page 2', '<span class="paginationSection">Page 2</span>');
```

Comment: What if the text isn't always `Page 2'?

Comment: @Barmar your answer is best I cannot vote you up as my reputation is less than 15 :(